# Unknown type name namespace

Tags: c++, c, opencv, android-ndk

I am currently working on Android native code. I have `Accessorries.h`

```
Accessories.h
#ifndef _ACCESSORIES_H_
#define _ACCESSORIES_H_
#define ANDROID    1
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/contrib/detection_based_tracker.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#define RETURN_OK  0
#define RETURN_MEMORY_ERROR 1
#define RETURN_PROCESS_ERROR  2
#define FACESIZE   0.2
#define WIDTH      400
#define HEIGHT     300

typedef struct{
     int col;
     int row;
     int width;
     int height;
}loc_rects;

typedef struct{

     int numofppl;
     int camera_idx;
     unsigned char *frame;//image buffer
     loc_rects *locs;
}container;

typedef struct{
   int ctrl;
   string frontxml;
   string profilexml;
}processParam;


typedef struct{
    DetectionBasedTracker::Parameters DetectorParams;
    DetectionBasedTracker front;
    DetectionBasedTracker profile;
}detectors;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

That `Accessories.h` is included in `Detection.h & Detection.cpp` and `camera.c`.
I got a lot of error for `unknown type name namespace`.
I use ndk-build for compiling the native code.
What could be wrong?
I have Path and Symbols setting as shown in the attached image.
I set the same setting for GNU C and GNU C++.[image]

EDIT:
This is one of the errors

```
C:/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits
/stl_vector.h:65:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
C:/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits
/stl_vector.h:66:1: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
In file included from C:/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libs
tdc++/4.6/include/vector:66:0,
                 from C:/Count//jni/include/opencv2/contrib/
detection_based_tracker.hpp:8,
                 from C:/Count//jni/Accessories.h:5,
                 from C:/Count//jni/FaceDetection.h:3,
                 from C:/Count//jni/com_astralink_orcas_api_
```

Thanks

Comment: hii
Could you paste the exact error

Comment: No I include in Detection.h and Camera.c only.

Comment: OK, do u get the error containing something like `asm ; ; ; ; ; redefinition was found here`

Comment: @yanivx yes I got those as well

Answer (score 2):

`using namespace` is C++ only. Use `#ifdef __cplusplus` for those declarations.

Comment: Looks like the file you include - `detection_based_tracker.hpp` - is C++ only. Maybe build everything as C++?

Comment: I comment out all. Then I include one by one. Once I include #include <string>. I got those namespace error.